# Session cannot be resolved to a type for sending mail via jsp

Tags: jsp, email, session, tomcat, smtp

### I want to send an email from my jsp page. I am using Apache Tomcat server and running on localhost. I referred this link http://www.javabeat.net/send-mail-jsp/ for guiding me. I also made an account on JangoSMTP   and provided the username and password in the code below.Yet, I get the error as :

```
An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /index2.jsp
Session cannot be resolved to a type
21:         props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
22:      
23:         //Get the Session object.
24:         Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
25:                 new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
26:                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
27:                         return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
```

### This is my index.html:-

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
        <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
        <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
        <%
            String result;
            //Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
            String to = "xyz@gmail.com";

            // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
            String from = "abc@gmail.com";
            final String username = "username";
            final String password = "password";

            // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
            String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

            //Get the Session object.
            Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                    password);
                        }
                    });

            try {
                // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

                // Set From: header field of the header.
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                // Set To: header field of the header.
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(to));

                // Set Subject: header field
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

                // Now set the actual message
                message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
                        + "email using JavaMailAPI in JSP ");

                // Send message
                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
                result = "Sent message successfully....";

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "Error: unable to send message....";

            }
        %>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Send Email using JSP</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center>
                <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
            </center>
            <p align="center">
                <%
                    out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
                %>
            </p>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Kindly tell me where is the error ! I googled a lot but couldn't find an answer. Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you have `mail.jar` in CLASSPATH or in lib folder?

Comment: @Rembo : in CLASSPATH. will it make a difference ?

Comment: Ok..I think that was the mistake. But now I get the error :Result: Error: unable to send message.... 
So, how should I resolve it ?

Comment: I get the error message in the console as :javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: relay.jangosmtp.net;

Comment: update your question with your current problem details and complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You include the .jar file.

$TOMCAT_HOME
    bin
    conf
    lib
    ...
    webapps
        
            test.jsp (Can be in any directory under  except WEB-INF)
            WEB-INF
                lib
                    mail.jar
                    activation.jar

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?